# The image not upload correctly, Angular 8 and ngx-image-compress

Tags: javascript, compression, firebase-storage

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDHWV.png)

I need to compress the image before to upload in storage of Firebase, I'm using ngx-image-compress.

The image yes upload to Storage of Firebase but it don't see.

In my code I'm using the next method (compressFile) of ngx-image-compress library

```
this.imageCompress.compressFile( event.target.result, 50, 50).then( result => {
  this.imagenComprimida = result;  
  this.guardarImagen(result); //This function call the Firestore method putString() to upload image b64
});
```

The variable *imagenComprimida* yes show it in html but not in Firestore Storage.

I don't understand why.

Also I tryed convert to File with the next method but it doesn't work either.

```
let imageFile = new File([result], "any", { type: 'image/jpeg' });
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!!

ngx-image-compress library has problems with Firestore. I don´t not why.

I found ng2-img-max and this library runs without problems.